# How can I replace the second occurrence of a string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
<Openings>
<opening><item><x>3</x><y>3</y><width>10.5</width><height>13.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening>
<opening><item><x>3</x><y>3</y><width>10.5</width><height>13.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening>
</Openings>
```

Based on the following value, for example 1, I want to replace the 2nd set of `<imgsrc></imgsrc>` (it is 0 based, so the 1st one is index 0, etc).

So the following output I want is if variable `opening = 1` is:

```
<Openings>
<opening><item><x>3</x><y>3</y><width>10.5</width><height>13.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening>
<opening><item><x>3</x><y>3</y><width>10.5</width><height>13.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc>myimage</imgsrc></item></opening>
</Openings>
```

Comment: [please show what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have no idea what to try

Comment: Parse the XML and do DOM manipulation.

Comment: jQuery would make short work of that problem. Manipulate it as a DOM object rather than a string if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc    = parser.parseFromString(XMLstring, "application/xml");

doc.getElementsByTagName('imgsrc')[1].innerHTML = 'myimage';
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3V7f/)

**EDIT:**

You could use a serializer to serialize the XML as a string

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var XMLString = serializer.serializeToString(doc);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3V7f/1/)

Comment: This works, but how can I convert the xml back into a string?

Comment: @AllisonC Since oyu've accepted the answer, how did you convert back?